# Getting val() of last checkbox checked by a user

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox

I am building an application that allows users to choose pizza toppings by checking/unchecking checkboxes.  The maximum I would like them to be able to select is 3 checkboxes.  Once they select 4, I would like to send an alert to the user and deselect the last_checked checkbox.  I have tried the following code to access the value of the most recent checked checkbox:

```
$("#Pizza #id_toppings").change(function() {
    var last_checked = $("#Pizza #id_toppings input[name='toppings']:checked").val()
    alert("The checkbox: '" + last_checked + "' changed");
});
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the value of the lowest checked box.  Any ideas how I can get it to return the last_checked box?  Example form is below.

```
<form action="/cart/" method="post" id="Pizza">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="hmgXKE0ximQjeAvhcSpLPa4WvL7dtUHW76D41WAgxMyzoBzTpzjeAMVuA99P3kSD">
    <input type="hidden" value="Pizza" name="menu_item" id="menu_item" />

    <p><label for="id_style">Style:</label> <select name="style" required id="id_style">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">Regular</option>

  <option value="2">Sicilian</option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_size">Size:</label> <select name="size" required id="id_size">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">Small</option>

  <option value="2">Large</option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_is_special">Gluten Free Dough:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="is_special" id="id_is_special"></p>
<p><label for="id_num_toppings">Number of Toppings:</label> <input type="number" name="num_toppings" required id="id_num_toppings"></p>
<p><label>Toppings:</label> <ul id="id_toppings">
    <li><label for="id_toppings_0"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="1" id="id_toppings_0">
 Pepperoni</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_1"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="2" id="id_toppings_1">
 Sausage</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_2"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="3" id="id_toppings_2">
 Mushrooms</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_3"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="4" id="id_toppings_3">
 Onions</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_4"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="5" id="id_toppings_4">
 Ham</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_5"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="6" id="id_toppings_5">
 Canadian Bacon</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_toppings_6"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="7" id="id_toppings_6">
 Pineapple</label>

</li>
</ul></p>

    <h5 id='price_indicator'>Price: $--.--</h5>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Pizza to Cart" />
</form>
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating this a little. You don't need to know the value of the last checked box. Instead when a box is checked you simply count how many are already checked. If the limit is hit, you cancel the event and stop the current box from being selected. See the duplicate I marked for an example of how this works.

Comment: attach the event listener to the toppings checkbox - https://codepen.io/mark-obrien/pen/GRgGMoq

Comment: I cant answer the question anymore but this Jquery Code works: $("[type ='checkbox']").click(function(ev) {   
    var checked = $("[name='toppings']:checked");
    if (checked.length >= 4) {
        let lastValue = ($(this).val())
        alert("The checkbox: '" + lastValue + "' changed");
        ev.preventDefault();

    }
 
});

Comment: I ended up using the following code which clears all the checkboxes if the user surpasses the limit.

Comment: var num_checked = $("input[name='toppings']:checked").length;
            var limit = 3;

            if (num_checked > limit) {
                alert("You can only select up to 3 toppings!");
                $("input[name='toppings']").prop('checked', false);
                $('#Pizza #id_num_toppings').val('0');
            }